# Maven dependency update on commandline

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, dependencies

I have a maven project that was built on the commandline for eclipse and one of the dependencies is constantly changing. How do I update this dependency on the commandline as I have heard that it is a bad idea to mix m2e plugin and commandline. Furthermore, I tried running `mvn eclipse:eclipse` on the command line and it messes up the project in eclipse removing the dependencies folder.

Comment: Please note: maven-eclipse-plugin (eclipse:eclipse) and m2e are not compatible.

Answer (score 108):

```
mvn clean install -U
```

`-U` means force update of dependencies.

Also, if you want to import the project into eclipse, I first run:

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse
```

then run

```
mvn eclipse:clean
```

Seems to work for me, but that's just my pennies worth.

Answer (score 63):

If you just want to re-load/update dependencies (I assume, with constantly changing you mean either SNAPSHOTS or local dependencies you update yourself), you can use

```
mvn dependency:resolve
```

Answer (score 3):

Simple run your project online i.e `mvn clean install` . It fetches all the latest dependencies that you mention in your pom.xml and built the project

Comment: doesnt that mean I have to also re-import the project in eclipse as a maven project?

Comment: @cobie Actually mvn eclipse:eclipse have to get the latest dependencies, as you said It is not working use the command I suggest and Just refresh your project in eclipse, that is enough

Answer (score 1):

```
mvn clean install -U
```

also make sure if you have your dependencies behind a VPN, you are connected to that VPN

Answer (score 0):

I recently stumbled upon an error in IntelliJ IDEA. Which arise, when I checkout in git an older branch which is uses older dependency versions in the pom.xml.

My codebase is getting littered with `java: package com.foo.bar does not exist` and

```
java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Baz
  location: class com.foo.bar
```

error messages.

The solution is to reload the project in the maven tab.

I tried to automate that, but it seems that it is due to the fact, that IntelliJ is not noticing, that these files need to be indexed.

Hope that this helps someone. And if someone got to know how to update that over the console or as an pre-run task, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

for updating dependencies ignoring ssl errors i run:

```
mvn dependency:resolve -U -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.insecure=true -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.allowall=true -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.ignore.validity.dates=true
```

Answer (score -7):

```
mvn -Dschemaname=public liquibase:update
```

Comment: wrong answer my buddy